# Python html table parsing, removing trailing character per column?

Tags: python, replace, beautifulsoup

Using various online resources I have managed to create a python script that will parse html tables and convert them to csv.

```
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get(sys.argv[1])

html = BeautifulSoup(url.content,'html.parser')

for br in html.find_all("br"):
    br.replace_with(",")

for tr in html.find_all('tr'):
    data = []   
    
    for td in tr.find_all('td'):
        data.append(td.text.strip())
        
    if data:
        print("{}".format('|'.join(data)))
```

It works great, but it doesn't account for some inconsistencies with the data I am parsing. Some fields only contain a br with no data either side of it and some fields end with a br. This means that some rows have columns that only contain a "," or end with a ",". I think what I need to do is remove any trailing "br" or "," on a per column basis.

Example of what I am trying to avoid

`|,|dog,|Italy|House|Sky Blue,|Chris|117|162|400,140|110|160|701|2019-06-27`

I want

`||dog|Italy|House|Sky Blue|Chris|117|162|400,140|110|160|701|2019-06-27`

Not really sure what my options are here. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
for td in tr.find_all('td'):
    data.append(td.text.strip().rstrip(","))
```

str.rstrip can take a parameter which is the trailing character to be removed.

reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rstrip.htm